# Update column with values of previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a table named `A` with the following structure and value:

```
Table A
id int PK,
col2 date,
col3 varchar(255) not null,
col4 int
```

And the values:

```
id      col2          col3       col4
1    2015-06-02      Hardisk     204
2    2015-06-03      Pendrive    204
3    2015-06-05      Monitor     204
```

Suppose I added some new data, so the value of `col4` is now changed to 1.

```
id      col2          col3       col4
1    2015-06-02      Hardisk      1
2    2015-06-03      Pendrive     1
3    2015-06-05      Monitor      1
4    2015-06-08      Printer      1
```

Suppose now I delete the row with `id` = 1. Now, I want to update `col4` back to 204. Like this:

```
id      col2          col3       col4
1    2015-06-02      Hardisk     204
2    2015-06-03      Pendrive    204
3    2015-06-05      Monitor     204
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Update table set col4 = 204. What is the problem

Comment: Please explain what defines the new value of `col4`? If I insert new row with `col4=123` then all rows should be updated to this value?

Comment: Try the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) MySQL statement. Or, even better, read an SQL tutorial first. Savvy?

Comment: "now I delete the row with id = 1"... but the result set you show next represents a deletion of the row with id = 4

Answer (score 0):

If It's not dynamic values you can do It in following:

```
UPDATE A
SET col4 = 204
```

If It's dynamic values, you can't just rollback values to previous in simple way. For that you should create something like col5 to store old values if you want to manipulate it in future.

1 way to achive It, for example you can create trigger for update. After update insert deleted values to new column (col5).